# how to get automatic parseJSON data in ajax request success callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, parsing

Well in 'success' callback function recieves data in native json string format and we have to convert it into javascript object using $.pareseJSON(data) inside the success callback. Is it  possible to receive already paresed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`jQuery.ajax()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method  will parse it automatically if you set `dataType:'json'`.

Comment: no it do not does that if returned data from server is array of objects .

Comment: @jason bourne: Yes it does if your JSON is valid.